# Randomize a Django queryset once, then iterate through it

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm writing an app that allows people to compare different pairs of hashtags.

**Model:**

```
class Competitors(models.Model):
    tag1 = models.ForeignKey('Hashtag', related_name='+')
    tag2 = models.ForeignKey('Hashtag', related_name='+')
    votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False)
```

**View:**

```
def compare_hashes(request, i=None):
    i = i or 0
    try:
        competitors = Competitors.objects.order_by('?')[i]
    except IndexError:
        return render(request, 'hash_to_hash.html',
            {'tag1': '', 'tag2': '', i: 0, 'done': True})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompetitorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if "yes" in request.POST:
                competitors.votes += 1
                competitors.save()
        i += 1
        return render(request, 'hash_to_hash.html',
                  {'tag1': competitors.tag1, 'tag2': competitors.tag2, i: i, 'done': False})

    else:
        return render(request, 'hash_to_hash.html',
                  {'tag1': competitors.tag1, 'tag2': competitors.tag2, i: i, 'done': False})
```

What I want to do is, per visitor, randomize the ordering of the Competitors objects, and then iterate through that randomized list.

**Questions:**

1. What's a better way of randomizing things besides o`bjects.order_by('?')`? I'm using MySQL, and I've seen some things on here about how `order_by('?')` + MySQL = SLOOOOOOOW. There were a couple of suggestions given, and I could easily implement something (I was thinking something along the lines of `random.shuffle(Competitors.objects.all())`), but I'm not sure where I'd put it, which leads me to my second question...
2. How do I make sure the randomization only happens once? I don't want to bore people by making them review the same pairs over and over again, and I don't want to throw off my results by having some pairs randomly showing up more than once. I want everybody to see the same list, just in different orders.

I suspect the answer lies in a Manager class, but, really, this all boils down to my lack of knowledge about what Django calls when.

*(I'm also having a problem where the results don't seem to be getting saved to my db, but that's a different, probably more easily solved, issue.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To maintain a consistent random order, you should order by a seeded random, with the seed stored in the session. Unfortunately you can't do this with pure django orm, but with mysql it's trivial:

```
import random
from django.conf import settings

# there might be a better way to do this...
DATABASE_ENGINE = settings.DATABASES[settings.DATABASES.keys()[0]]['ENGINE'].split('.')[-1]

def compare_hashes(request, i=None):
    competitors = Competitors.objects.all()

    if DATABASE_ENGINE == 'mysql':
        if not request.session.get('random_seed', False):
            request.session['random_seed'] = random.randint(1, 10000)
        seed = request.session['random_seed']
        competitors = competitors.extra(select={'sort_key': 'RAND(%s)' % seed}).order_by('sort_key')

    # now competitors is randomised but consistent for the session
    ...
```

I doubt performance would be an issue in most situations; if it is your best bet would be to create some indexed sort_key columns in your database which are updated periodically with random values, and order on one of those for the session.

Answer (score 4):

Tried Greg's answer on PostgreSQL and got an error, because there are no random function with seed there. After some thinking, I went another way and gave that job to Python, which likes such tasks more:

```
def order_items_randomly(request, items):
    if not request.session.get('random_seed', False):
        request.session['random_seed'] = random.randint(1, 10000)
    seed = request.session['random_seed']
    random.seed(seed)
    items = list(items)
    random.shuffle(items)
    return items
```

Works quick enough on my 1.5k items queryset.

P.S. And as it is converting queryset to list, it's better to run this function just before pagination.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, based largely on Greg's awesome suggestion above:

View:

```
def compare_hashes(request, i=0):
    i = int(i)
    competitors = Competitors.objects.all()
    DATABASE_ENGINE = settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'].split('.')[-1]
    if DATABASE_ENGINE == 'mysql':
        if not request.session.get('random_seed',False):
            ints = xrange(10000)
            request.session['random_seed'] = sample(ints,1)[0]
        seed = request.session['random_seed']
        competitors = competitors.extra(select={'sort_key': 'RAND({})'.format(seed)})
        randomized_competitors = competitors.order_by('sort_key')
    try:
        chosen_competitor = randomized_competitors[i]
    except IndexError:
        return render(request, 'hash_to_hash.html',
        {'tag1': '', 'tag2': '', i: 0, 'done': True})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompetitorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if "yes" in request.POST:
                competitors.votes += 1
                competitors.save()
            i += 1
    return render(request, 'hash_to_hash.html',
              {'tag1': chosen_competitor.tag1, 'tag2': chosen_competitor.tag2, 'action':'/hash/{}'.format(i), 'done': False})
```

Template (which uses [Django-bootstrap-toolkit](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit) and still needs some work):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}
{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}
{% block big_title %}Title{% endblock %}
{% block main-content %}
    <h3>Hash-to-Hash</h3>
    {% if done %}
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
            <h4>You're Done!</h4>
            <p>Thanks so much!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6" id="tag1">
                <h4>{{ tag1.text }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="span6" id="tag2">
                <h4>{{ tag2.text }}</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="span8">
            <form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <!-- {{ form|as_bootstrap }} -->
           {% bootstrap_form form layout="vertical" %}
           <div class="form-actions">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="yes">
                   YES, I think these two tags are co-referential
               </button>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="no">
                   NO, I don't think these two tags are co-referential
               </button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The URLconf looks like this: `url(r'^hash/(\d*)$', compare_hashes)`

Thanks again!